# AngularJS - dividing ng-repeat into different filters or groups

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a list that I would like grouped into different sections on the page.

I currently have it divided like so (code is shortened to be easier to read) :

```
<div ng-repeat="role in roles | filter: { Type: 'AA'}">
   <input class="styled" type="checkbox" value="{{ role.Value }}" />
   <label>{{ role.Name }}</label>
</div>
<div ng-repeat="role in roles | filter: { Type: 'BB'}">
   <input class="styled" type="checkbox" value="{{ role.Value }}" />
   <label>{{ role.Name }}</label>
</div>
<div ng-repeat="role in roles | filter: { Type: 'CC'}">
   <input class="styled" type="checkbox" value="{{ role.Value }}" />
   <label>{{ role.Name }}</label>
</div>
<div ng-repeat="role in roles | filter: { Type: 'DD'}">
   <input class="styled" type="checkbox" value="{{ role.Value }}" />
   <label>{{ role.Name }}</label>
</div>
<div ng-repeat="role in roles | filter: { Type: 'EE'}">
   <input class="styled" type="checkbox" value="{{ role.Value }}" />
   <label>{{ role.Name }}</label>
</div>
...
```

I think this loops through the list for each group, which doesnt seem efficient.

I was curious if there was a better way to do this? For example, having just a single ng-repeat at the top and filtering within the child sections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick, if I understand correctly.

```js
angular.module("roleApp", [])
  .controller('myCtrl', myCtrl);

function myCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.people = [{
    name: 'Penelope',
    role: 'AA'
  }, {
    name: 'Franklin',
    role: 'BB'
  }, {
    name: 'Stewart',
    role: 'CC'
  }, {
    name: 'Keith',
    role: 'DD'
  }, {
    name: 'Paula',
    role: 'EE'
  }, {
    name: 'Maria',
    role: 'BB'
  }, {
    name: 'Claudette',
    role: 'EE'
  }];


  var indexedRoles = [];

  $scope.rolesToFilter = function() {
    indexedRoles = [];
    return $scope.people;
  };

  $scope.filterRoles = function(person) {
    var roleIsNew = indexedRoles.indexOf(person.role) == -1;
    if (roleIsNew) {
      indexedRoles.push(person.role);
    }
    return roleIsNew;
  }
}
```

```css
h1 {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 0;
}
h2 {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
p {
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-left: 1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="roleApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <h1>ROLES:</h1>
  <div ng-repeat="personPerRole in rolesToFilter() | filter:filterRoles">
    <h2>{{personPerRole.role}} :</h2>
    <p ng-repeat="person in people | filter:{role: personPerRole.role}">{{person.name}}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Great! I was able to take your example and expand on it for what I needed. I forgot we could make custom filters like this. Thank you!

Comment: Awesome. Glad I could help. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

I could see one way to do it, by taking `TypeFileter` array which will have all the filter values.

**Markup**

```
<div ng-repeat="role in roles | filter: { Type: TypeFileter[$index]}">
   <input class="styled" type="checkbox" value="{{ role.Value }}" />
   <label>{{ role.Name }}</label>
</div>
```

**Code**

```
$scope.TypeFileter = ['AA', 'BB', 'CC', 'DD', 'EE', /*... so on */]
```

Comment: I was able to take yours and MaxRocket's examples to create my custom fitler. Thanks!